# Avoid the escape key in VsVim

Tags: visual-studio, vim, vi, vsvim

Vim has the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> that can be used instead of the escape key <kbd>ESC</kbd>. This shortcut is used by Visual Studio to open the Team Explorer. How can I replace this shortcut in order to use it like Vim?

Answer (score 4):

To make this work you just need to switch control of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to VsVim via the options page:

- Tools -> Options -> VsVim
- Keyboard
- Change the combo box to VsVim for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

Comment: This option does not exists in that menu.

Comment: @jgarciad Can you see what key the <kbd>Ctrl+[</kbd> is bound to on your solution?  Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard.  Go to the input box, hit <kbd>Ctrl+[</kdg> and see what commands it is bound to.